# Recipe or script to generate a python wheel

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-wheel

I'm looking for a way to generate a Python wheel from a library that is already succesfuly installed in my python libraries.

The goal is to generate manylinux wheels for PyQt4. These wheels will allow users without sudo privileges to install PyQt4 in a virtualenv, on a system where Qt is not necessarily installed.

I solved the first part of the problem: installing PyQt4 and dependencies (Qt4 and SIP) on a CentOS5 docker.
Now I need to figure out how to create the wheel file. I believe the general idea is to bundle all installed files in a zip file renamed to .whl.

I'm looking for help on the specifics: computing the hashes of all the files, including the Qt files (which files are required? where should I put non-python libraries in the .whl archive and how should i register them for pip to figure out what to do with them?)

I cannot find tutorials/recipes/examples of generating a .whl without using a setup.py file. I find this odd, surely someone else must have attempted to package a tricky dependency as a .whl to simplify the install procedure of his library for users.

**EDIT:**

The procedure for doing the hashes seems to be reasonably well documented in the PEP 427. My main question is about how to include Qt4 inside the wheel.

This is the content of my Qt install folder:

```
[root@b865208e357b PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.4]# ls /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/
bin  demos  doc  examples  imports  include  lib  mkspecs  phrasebooks  plugins  q3porting.xml  tests  translations
```

Should I take only `lib` (98 Mb),  or the whole install (400+ Mb)? Should I put it at the root of the PyQt4 install in my site-packages? Is PyQt4 going to be able to find the Qt library, or do I need to edit a file to register it (tell PyQt4 to look in the current path rather than the usual library path)?